# Is this position competitive?

Tags: job-search

A PhD position in the Linkedin has 20 applications.

Does it mean this position is very competitive, and It is hard for me to be selected?

This position is in the Netherlands and in the ML/AI field and in a good university.

Comment: Note that unless the application is on LinkedIn itself, the number of applications may just be the people who clicked the "Apply" link. It doesn't mean that all of those people completed the application (or even started it).

Comment: @BSMP Yea, I agree. It also means there might be many people who didn't click this 'Apply' link, but directly apply it in the Uni website...

Answer (score 6):

> A PhD position in the Linkedin has 20 applications.
>
> Does it mean this position is very competitive, and It is hard for me
> to be selected?

It only means that 20 people have applied.

That may mean it's competitive. It may mean it would be hard for you to be selected. It may mean that this is obviously a terrific job for a terrific organization and everyone wants to be a part of it. Or it may mean that 20 others are giving it a shot but are completely unqualified, and the company is waiting to hear from that one winner - maybe you.

It shouldn't matter. If you have any confidence in yourself at all, apply anyway, and demonstrate why they should hire you rather than the other 20. Isn't a good position worth fighting for?

If you have no confidence in yourself, then find an opening where nobody else has applied. Maybe they will hire you. Maybe not.

Answer (score 2):

> Does it mean this position is very competitive, and It is hard for me to be selected?

This is not something you should be worrying about when looking for a job.

If you are interested in this position then apply to it the same as you would apply to any other position.  As with any position that you apply for, if you are considered to be the best candidate of the pool of candidates then you will be offered the position.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this position competitive?

It depends on your definition of "competitive". It could be.

However, some software engineer positions in LinkedIn may have more than 200 applications per job.

Often, I have seen many software developer positions that have more than 50 applications per job.

Comment: Thanks. I like this position, but... Anyway, it sounds like this position is very tense and I need to take much time on preparing it.